# how to iterate though list of numbers and use key as string in terraform

Tags: terraform

Terraform syntax question. I am trying to minimise the logic creating security groups by simply looping over a list of local variables, here is the example

```
locals {
  egress = {
    udp = [
      53,
      123
    ]
  }
  ingress = {
    tcp = [
      443,
      22,
    ]
  }
}
```

and a resource:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp" {
  #for_each         = [ for k, v in local.ingress : local.ingress.k => v ]
  #for_each         = [ for port in local.ingress : port => port ]
  #for_each         = [ for proto in local.ingress : proto ]
  #for_each         = [ for k, v in local.ingress : k ]
  for_each          = local.ingress
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = each.value
  to_port           = each.value
  protocol          = tostring(each.key)
  self              = true
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.main.id
}
```

I have tried everything but nothing works. I guess I do not understand the meaning of [ for ... ] and { for ... }

The best result so far is as above, using simple `for_each = local.ingress`, but I get the error:

```
 Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on sg-rules/main.tf line 38, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp":
│   38:   from_port         = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "from_port": number required.
```

when I convert each.value to number using `from_port = tonumber(each.value)` I get another error:

```
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│
│   on sg-rules/main.tf line 38, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp":
│   38:   from_port         = tonumber(each.value)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling tonumber(v)
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert tuple to number.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing the local to be a bit more loop friendly...

Something like this

```
locals {
  ingress = {
    443 : "tcp",
    22 : "tcp"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp" {
  for_each          = local.ingress
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = each.key
  to_port           = each.key
  protocol          = each.value
  self              = true
  security_group_id = "sg-123456"
}
```

The TF plan output now looks like:

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_security_group_rule.in_tcp["22"] will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp" {
      + from_port                = 22
      + id                       = (known after apply)
      + protocol                 = "tcp"
      + security_group_id        = "sg-123456"
      + security_group_rule_id   = (known after apply)
      + self                     = true
      + source_security_group_id = (known after apply)
      + to_port                  = 22
      + type                     = "ingress"
    }

  # aws_security_group_rule.in_tcp["443"] will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp" {
      + from_port                = 443
      + id                       = (known after apply)
      + protocol                 = "tcp"
      + security_group_id        = "sg-123456"
      + security_group_rule_id   = (known after apply)
      + self                     = true
      + source_security_group_id = (known after apply)
      + to_port                  = 443
      + type                     = "ingress"
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: This is a nice clean answer, I add the below just as a suplemental if the OP's data structure cannot be changed. The following is an expression which can convert the existing data structure to the one in this answer. `merge([for proto, ports in local.ingress: {for port in ports: port=> proto}]...)`

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic. I wanted to keep my code dumb simple but yours is still simple, and requires only one resource. However, since terraform will only accept one unique key, means I can only assign port to one protocol. I cannot create port 53 tcp and udp at the same time. Nevertheless port 53 is not a common case. Thank you. On the other hand I can still use your structure, change protocol to CIDR block and keep it to one protocol only. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: `local.ingress` is an object with key = "tcp" and value = [443, 22]. Second: `foreach` only accepts map or set of strings. You want a map indexed by "<proto_port>" like this:

```
{
  "tcp_22" = {
    "port" = 22
    "proto" = "tcp"
  }
  "tcp_443" = {
    "port" = 443
    "proto" = "tcp"
  }
}
```

This is how you do it:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp" {
  for_each          = {
    for p in flatten([
      for proto, ports in local.ingress: [
        for port in ports: { proto = proto, port = port }
      ]
    ]): "${p.proto}_${p.port}" => p
  }
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = tonumber(each.value.port)
  to_port           = tonumber(each.value.port)
  protocol          = tostring(each.value.proto)
  self              = true
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.main.id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using strings instead of numbers within your locals and using "toset" function in the for_each block. Then you create a aws_security_group_rule for each protocol respectively:

```
locals {
  egress = {
    udp = [
      "53",
      "123"
    ]
  }
  ingress = {
    tcp = [
      "443",
      "22",
    ]
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "in_tcp" {
  for_each          = toset(local.ingress.tcp)
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = tonumber(each.value)
  to_port           = tonumber(each.value)
  protocol          = "tcp"
  self              = true
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.main.id
}
```

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "out_udp" {
  for_each          = toset(local.egress.udp)
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = tonumber(each.value)
  to_port           = tonumber(each.value)
  protocol          = "udp"
  self              = true
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.main.id
}
```